# Drawing table with multi rows and columns

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow

So I am trying to figure this out:

[image]

Can you help me out with the layout? Those multi rows are hard to draw.

Working on a MWE right  now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{4}{Y|}}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Similarity} 
  &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Movielens 1M}&\\
\cline{2-4}
             &KNNBasic       &KNNBaseline & KNNMeans\\
\hline
MSD      &0.9345            &0.9345       & 0.9345  \\
\hline
User based &0.9345             &0.9345       &0.9345  \\
\hline
Item based     &0.9345   &0.9345     &0.9345  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need multirow for this, if I understand well what you want. Just use `\cline{2-5}` in the relevant places.

Comment: How can I put MSD, Cosine and Pearson behind User Based and Item Based? I’m stuck there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reproduction of your first table, without colors, and with some entries vertically entered, which I think is nicer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{Y|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Similarity modules}}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Mean RMSE for Movielens 1M dataset} \\
\cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & KNN Basic       &KNN Baseline & KNN With Means\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{MSD}      & Item Based & 0.9144            & 0.8853       & 0.8854  \\
\cline{2-5}
      & User Based & 0.9230            & 0.8953       & 0.9292  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Cosine} & Item based & 0.9994             & 0.9840       & 0.8936  \\
\cline{2-5}
 & User based & 0.9767             & 0.9011       & 0.9394  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Pearson} & Item based     & 0.9741   & 0.8825    & 0.8821  \\
\cline{2-5}
 & User based     & 0.9481   & 0.8879    & 0.9163  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting document]

If you want the table to be colored you have to insert `\rowcolor`, `\cellcolor`, and `\arrayrulecolor` commands from the `colortbl` package and use `\color` commands for some of the texts.

Comment: It was not that easy! Thank you very much Piet, I really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, not the best, but it works for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{3}{Y|}}
\hline
\multirow{2 }{*}{\textbf{Similarity}} 
  &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{RMSE}}   \\
\cline{2-3}
             &   Movielens        & Movielens \\
\hline
Cosine &         0.9345                &0.9345         \\
\hline
Pearson    &      0.9345               &0.9345       \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how the table in your answer and the request in the question are related. Also, is there a connection to the following question? [Problem getting rid of column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491868/134144)?