# Problem getting rid of column

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I need to get rid of the last column. Could you give me a hand?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{4}{Y|}}
\hline
\multirow{2 }{*}{\textbf{Similarity}} 
  &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{RMSE}}  & \\
\cline{2-4}
             &   Movielens        & Movielens  \\
\hline
Cosine &         NA                &.3412         \\
\hline
Pearson    &      0.2341               &1.1       \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make three changes:

- replace

  ```
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{4}{Y|}}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{3}{Y|}}
  ```
- delete the `&` symbol after `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{RMSE}}`, and
- replace `\cline{2-4}` with `\cline{2-3}`.

A separate observation: Since the width of the `tabularx` environment is set to `\textwidth`, you should insert a `\noindent` instruction immediately before `\begin{tabularx}`.

Comment: Done! Thank you very much!!!